# c program - create bursts of fixed size

Tags: c, buffer

I am trying to implement token bucket algorithm in C ... but I am stuck in how to create bursts of fixed size like 10MB , 20MB , 100 MB , etc .

my code to send 2MB data

```
for(i=0;i<2047;i++)
   buffer[i] = 'a' ;         // some char
if(sendto(sock_fd, buffer , 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
            perror("\nmessage sending failed");
else
        printf("message  sent successfully");
```

I think , I just need to fill the buffer with chars with the amount we want... is it the right way ??
I think this would consume much memory for the `buffer` array ??
Any better and standard way to do this ??

Comment: Could you clarify how does it work, why it doesn't and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: the memory of your buffer array is already allocated and fixed (2048), so it will not consume much memory   !!

Comment: I mean , the client sends a burst of 100MB for 2 seconds i.e 200MB of data...so how to do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about trying to implement a specific data rate, well that's a much more complicated problem.  If you just want to send more data, then put your above code in a loop, and do it multiple times. (eg: to send 10MB, do your loop 5 times).  To spread it out over a number of seconds, you can add a sleep(1) in the loop, or some other type of delay (nanosleep maybe).

An approximate method for doing a data rate would be to use a smaller buffer size, say a few K, and then calculate the delay and number of loops needed to send it.  For example, using a 32K buffer, to send 200MB in 2 seconds you would loop 200M/32K = 6400 times. The delay in
the loop would be at most 2s/6400 = 312500 nanoseconds.  Of course, this won't be anywhere near exact, due to the time taken to execute the code, the time needed to send the packets through the socket, any network delays and packet loss, etc.  But it might be close enough for your purposes.